# Linux driver support for OV4689

Tags: camera, linux, driver

I am working on Camera driver in Linux.
We used camera module with OV4689 IC.

Below is the link
https://www.arducam.com/product/1-3-ov4689-sensor-standalone-camera-module-uc4689-a46/

Any one used this module? If yes can you share the Linux driver source for this.
We connected this module to MIPI interface.

Thanks and Regards,

Devendra